# PyCharm keymap modifier keys

Tags: pycharm, hotkeys, keymapping

I am trying to change the keymap in Pycharm, and it seems that there are only 4 (3 for linux/windows) modifier keys: Shift, Cmd (for mac), Ctrl, and Alt (and thus only 3 for linux/windows).

Is there a possibility to get more modifier keys, for example distinguish between left and right shift, left and right alt, or the windows key?